# Creating a Jagged array instead of 2 dimension array in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I would like to avoid using a 2 dimensional array for a situation where I have X number of Rows and each Row can have different number of elements.

I do not know how many rows i have ahead of time.

So am thinking of somehow using Lists that contain Lists that contain "widgets".

Where widgets are the data i need to store at each row/column location.

Is this doable and if so, i am not sure how to create the Row List with Column lists containing the widgets and then traverse the result after it is created.

I've done alot of googling but havent found samples that show lists of lists of "something" or collections or arraylists... that contain another list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this:

```
    Dim Rows As New List(Of List(Of String))


    Rows.Add(New List(Of String))
    Rows.Item(0).Add("Test1")
    'Row with one item

    Rows.Add(New List(Of String))
    Rows.Item(1).Add("Test2")
    Rows.Item(1).Add("Test2")
    'Row with two items

    Rows.Add(New List(Of String))
    'Row with three items

    For Each row In Rows
        For Each item In row
            Debug.Print(item)
        Next
    Next
```

Probably not the ideal way but I've used something like this before and it's met my needs when tweaked a little.